# Time capsule over ethernet is incredibly slow

Tags: network, time-capsule, ethernet, afp

I am transferring files from my Time Capsule (4th Generation, 2TB, model A1409) to my laptop (Ubuntu) via the Apple Filing Protocol. The Time Capsule is connected directly to the laptop via an ethernet cable (wifi on the laptop is disabled): standard LAN port to standard laptop ethernet interface. The Time Capsule is not being used by any other device (i.e. it is disconnected from my primary router; no laptops/mobiles/etc are connected to it physically/wirelessly aside from the Ubuntu laptop).

The transfer speeds are incredibly slow: ~260kB/sec. I am transferring several large files that equate to ~7GB, which is taking several hours to transfer.

Why is the network speed so slow? How do I increase the speed?

Answer (score 1):

- Configure the ethernet interface in [Ubuntu to use Gigabit in full duplex](https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html)
- Reset the network card by powering down the laptop and [unplugging it from mains for a few seconds](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1480328&page=2&p=9290894#post9290894)
- To effectively use Gigabit ethernet, use a Cat 5e or Cat 6 cable
- Start the copy after a reboot of the devices (with WiFi and other connections disabled)